# How to change the font for number in allowframebreak generated frames?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{red}\insertframetitle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Some Text}
  \Blindtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How I can change the color of I, II and so on?[image]

Comment: Try `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the foreground `fg` of the `frametitle` color you can add:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}
```

... to the preamble. See also [17.2.3 Setting Beamer’s Colors](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjBjK6Zo__TAhWHzxQKHeqgADkQFgg2MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftug.ctan.org%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Fbeamer%2Fdoc%2Fbeameruserguide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG7pBqOz-mgDrq76r3Zh_diGivlwA&cad=rja) in the `beamer` manual.

**Solution:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Some Text}
  \Blindtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,

`\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}`

did not work, I had to use

`\setbeamercolor{frametitle continuation}{fg=red}`,

see [8 Creating Frames](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#section.8) in the beamer manual